# django South failing with self referencing models

Tags: django, heroku

I have a self referencing model

```
class Category(models.Model):
category_name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
parent_category= models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
category_user_number=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.category_name
```

This model works locally when I use south but when I upload to heroku `parent_category` gives an error

```
column mysite_category.parent_category_id does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `heroku run python manage.py migrate` when you push to heroku.

Comment: I did but then it gave me this error `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: column "demo" of relation "uTriga_category" does not exist
` demo is an attribute I used earlier but have deleted it. I deleted demo, wrote the new code above and even deleted the app on heroku and started all over. Its Just that when I when I change `parent_category` to any other field apart from a self reference. it works on heroku.

Comment: Was there a migration to remove the `demo` attribute?

Comment: No I just deleted the app on heroku, removed demo from the model and created the app again...starting all over. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It probably still exists in the database.  If you look at your migration file, do you still see the `demo` attribute defined on your model?

Comment: no Its not I deleted the demo related files in the migration folder a long time ago